# How to visualise filters in a CNN with PyTorch

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

I'm new to deep learning and Pytorch. I want to visual my filter in my CNN model so that I can iterate layer in the CNN model that I define. But I meet error like below.

**error: 'CNN' object is not iterable**

The CNN object is my model.

My iteration code is like below：

```
for index, layer in enumerate(self.model):             
# Forward pass layer by layer
    x = layer(x)
```

my model code like below：

```
class CNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CNN,self).__init__()
        self.Conv1 = nn.Sequential( # input image size (1,28,20)
            nn.Conv2d(1, 16, 5, 1, 2), # outputize (16,28,20)
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(2),           #outputize (16,14,10)
        )
        self.Conv2 = nn.Sequential( # input ize ? (16,,14,10)
            nn.Conv2d(16, 32, 5, 1, 2),   #output size(32,14,10)
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(2),        #output size (32,7,5)
        )
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(32 * 7 * 5, 800) 
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(800,500)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(500,10)
        #self.fc4 = nn.Linear(200,10)
        
    def forward(self,x):
        x = self.Conv1(x)
        x = self.Conv2(x)
        x = x.view(x.size(0), -1)
        x = self.fc1(x)
        x = F.dropout(x)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = self.fc2(x)
        x = F.dropout(x)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = self.fc3(x)
        #x = F.relu(x)
        #x = self.fc4(x)
        return x
```

So anyone can tell me how can I solve this problem.

Comment: What do you mean by visualizing filter?

Comment: Like this [link](https://blog.keras.io/how-convolutional-neural-networks-see-the-world.html),but i want to implement it use pytroch, so i want to iterate layer in model.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Essentially, you will need to access the features in your model and transpose those matrices into the right shape first, then you can visualise the filters

```py
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from torchvision import utils

    def visTensor(tensor, ch=0, allkernels=False, nrow=8, padding=1): 
        n,c,w,h = tensor.shape

        if allkernels: tensor = tensor.view(n*c, -1, w, h)
        elif c != 3: tensor = tensor[:,ch,:,:].unsqueeze(dim=1)

        rows = np.min((tensor.shape[0] // nrow + 1, 64))    
        grid = utils.make_grid(tensor, nrow=nrow, normalize=True, padding=padding)
        plt.figure( figsize=(nrow,rows) )
        plt.imshow(grid.numpy().transpose((1, 2, 0)))


    if __name__ == "__main__":
        layer = 1
        filter = model.features[layer].weight.data.clone()
        visTensor(filter, ch=0, allkernels=False)

        plt.axis('off')
        plt.ioff()
        plt.show()
```

You should be able to get a grid visual.
[image]

There are a few more visualisation techniques, you can study them [here](https://github.com/utkuozbulak/pytorch-cnn-visualizations)

Comment: FYI - I think the tensor.shape should be `n, c, h, w` according to Pytorch documentation (https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Conv2d.html).

Comment: It raised AttributeError: 'CNNModel' object has no attribute 'features', could anyone told me why. thanks a lot

Answer (score 9):

First, let me state some facts so that there is no confusion.
A Convolutional Layer (also called a filter) is composed of kernels. When we say that we are using a kernel size of 3 or (3,3), the actual shape of the kernel is 3-d and not 2d. A kernel's depth matches the number of channels in the input to the convolutional layer. For example,

input image shape (CxHxW): (3, 128, 128) and now we apply a Conv Layer with number of output channels 128 and kernel size 3.

```
self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=3, out_channels=128, kernel_size=8, stride = 4, padding = 2)
```

The output shape will be (128, 32, 32),
the  shape of the kernel will be (3, 8, 8)
and the shape of the filter will be (num_kernels, kernel_depth, kernel_height, kernel_width): (128, 3, 8, 8)
The number of kernels in the filter is the same as the number of output channels.

It's easy to visualize the filters of the first layer since they have a depth dimension of either 1 or 3 depending on whether your input is grayscale or a color image respectively.

```py
# instantiate model
conv = ConvModel()

# load weights if they haven't been loaded
# skip if you're directly importing a pretrained network
checkpoint = torch.load('model_weights.pt')
conv.load_state_dict(checkpoint)


# get the kernels from the first layer
# as per the name of the layer
kernels = conv.first_conv_layer.weight.detach().clone()

#check size for sanity check
print(kernels.size())

# normalize to (0,1) range so that matplotlib
# can plot them
kernels = kernels - kernels.min()
kernels = kernels / kernels.max()
filter_img = torchvision.utils.make_grid(kernels, nrow = 12)
# change ordering since matplotlib requires images to 
# be (H, W, C)
plt.imshow(filter_img.permute(1, 2, 0))

# You can directly save the image as well using
img = save_image(kernels, 'encoder_conv1_filters.png' ,nrow = 12)
```

[image: filters of an autoencoder]

Comment: What about the second layer? For ex. [32, 16, 5, 5]  how to visualize this?

Answer (score 2):

```
def imshow_filter(img,row,col):
    print('-------------------------------------------------------------')
    plt.figure()
    for i in range(len(filters)):
        w = np.array([0.299, 0.587, 0.114]) #weight for RGB
        img = filters[i]
        img = np.transpose(img, (1, 2, 0))
        img = img/(img.max()-img.min())
        img = np.dot(img,w)

        plt.subplot(row,col,i+1)
        plt.imshow(img,cmap= 'gray')
        plt.xticks([])
        plt.yticks([])
    plt.show()
# swap color axis because
# numpy image: H x W x C
# torch image: C X H X W
filters = net.conv1.weight.data.cpu().numpy()
imshow_filter(filters)
```

this should be work on your code

Comment: I'm getting `TypeError: imshow_filter() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'row' and 'col'` what should be those values?

Comment: The row and col is the number of rows and columns of the visualization image. For example, if you have 32 filters in your first layer, you can display them as 4 x 8 or 8 x 4 image, or whatever you like if row * col = your filter number