# is it possible to visualize the convolutions layers in this model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

How could I visualize the first layer in the tensorflow model. Could you please help?

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Dense, Flatten, Dropout

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(16, (3,3), 1, activation='relu', input_shape=(256,256,3)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D())
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3,3), 1, activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D())
model.add(Conv2D(16, (3,3), 1, activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D())
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile('adam', loss=tf.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(), metrics=['accuracy'])
model.Summary()
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "visualize"? Are you trying to use your own imagination to think about what it looks like, or do you want the computer to draw some kind of diagram? In the latter case, what are the rules it should use? Please read [ask] and note well that this is **not a discussion forum**; we [cannot](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236) "help" but we can answer **specific** questions.

Comment: what i meant to plot what is happening in the training, to see an image after applying the filters, i guess it is called visualization. thanks

Comment: What information should be in the image? For example, if it's a plot, do you mean like a line graph? What should be the x axis and y axis?

Comment: This is too vague to be answerable, there are too many possible visualizations.

Comment: @ you can't directly show the first layer, you can see the whole model

Comment: i want something like Alexnet  https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmaikelshortcuts.blogspot.com%2F2014%2F12%2Falexnet-first-convolution-filters.html&psig=AOvVaw0iSjJbTiNd-SaUV7_JogTl&ust=1675903709247000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CA0QjhxqFwoTCLiqtv7ZhP0CFQAAAAAdAAAAABAD

Comment: That has been asked multiple times here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39361943/how-can-visualize-tensorflow-convolution-filters and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55594969/how-to-visualise-filters-in-a-cnn-with-pytorch some first is always good

Answer (score 0):

You can use   `plot_model` to visualize the model. you can't directly visualize only the first layer

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Dense, Flatten, Dropout
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(16, (3,3), 1, activation='relu', input_shape=(256,256,3)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D())
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3,3), 1, activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D())
model.add(Conv2D(16, (3,3), 1, activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D())
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile('adam', loss=tf.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(), metrics=['accuracy'])
#model. Summary()
#Visualization code
from keras.utils import plot_model
plot_model(model, to_file='model.png', show_shapes=True)
```

https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/get_started , Tensorboard also can help you